# Simple SQL query to get phrase pairs from a translations table

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is probably the noobiest SQL question ever, and I'm almost positive there's a `JOIN` or something in PostgreSQL for this, but I can't find it so I'm using a naive method. Here's a bit about my schema:

**phrases**:

```
CREATE TABLE phrases
(
  phrase_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  language character varying(4) NOT NULL,
  text text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT phrases_pk PRIMARY KEY (phrase_id)
)
```

**translations**:

```
CREATE TABLE translations
(
  source_id bigint NOT NULL,
  destination_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT translations_pk PRIMARY KEY (source_id, destination_id)
)
```

I use the following query to get 100 phrases (for two language pairs). This requires limiting the results to the language pairs, then finding their translations in the `translations` table:

```
SELECT P1.phrase_id, P1.language, P1.text, P2.phrase_id, P2.language, P2.text
FROM phrases P1, phrases P2, translations T
WHERE (P1.language = 'eng' AND P2.language = 'fra'
    AND P1.phrase_id = T.source_id
    AND P2.phrase_id = T.destination_id)
LIMIT 100
```

For what it's worth, the query runs in 34 ms with ~7.5m rows in the `translations` table, and 1m rows in the `phrases` table. I'll end up doing full text searches on the phrases table though, so I want to make the translation lookup as efficient as possible (as the `translations` table will grow ~5x faster than `phrases`). Lookup in `translations` is also the most common operation in this database.

Are there any fancy methods of accomplishing this more elegantly/efficiently in PostgreSQL?

**P.S.** - There is no foreign key constraint in the `translations` table because I am still in the process of sanitizing the database and removing old records. Importing into Postgres was impossible with the FK due to entries missing from `phrases`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using more vertical space when you write a query to make it easier to read. That said, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    P1.phrase_id, 
    P1.language, 
    P1.text, 
    P2.phrase_id, 
    P2.language, 
    P2.text
FROM    phrases P1
INNER JOIN translations T
    ON P1.phrase_id = T.source_id
INNER JOIN phrases P2 
    ON P2.phrase_id = T.destination_id
WHERE   P1.language = 'eng' 
AND     P2.language = 'fra'
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: There's a syntax error after the second `INNER JOIN` (extra `)`). Also, oddly enough the `EXPLAIN` for my query and yours give the exact same output... It still ends up running a nested loop, but maybe that can't be avoided... +1 for the formatting suggestion though :) Do you have any other ideas? I'm not sure if this can even get more efficient now =/

Comment: Whoops, good catch. I'm not surprised the query plan is the same (as it is doing the same thing) but yours are ANSI-92 joins and those can be problematic. [This article](http://www.straightpathsql.com/archives/2012/11/sql-server-join-syntax-its/) may be interesting to you on that topic.

Comment: Ah, good read! I'll change that right away :P